# Spring Boot multiple databases

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to get Spring Boot running with multiple databases
I've found [How to use 2 or more databases with spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362546/how-to-use-2-or-more-databases-with-spring) and http://xantorohara.blogspot.com.au/2013/11/spring-boot-jdbc-with-multiple.html which have been helpfully. However, the class TomcatDataSourceConfiguration isn't included in version 1.2.4. How can I get this working using the newer versions?

EDIT: Now I'm getting the error `No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined`

DatabaseConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.weather")
    public DataSource weatherDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean weatherManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(weatherDataSource())
                .packages(User1.class)
                .persistenceUnit("user2")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.weather_alerts")
    public DataSource weatherAlertsDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean weatherAlertsManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(weatherAlertsDataSource())
                .packages(User1.class)
                .persistenceUnit("user1")
                .build();
    }
}
```

User1.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users1")
public class User1 {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name1;

    public User1() {}

    public User1(String name1) {
        this.name1 = name1;
    }

    // Getter Setters

}
```

User2.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users2")
public class User2 {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name1;

    public User2() {}

    public User1(String name1) {
        this.name2 = name2;
    }

    // Getter Setters

}
```

User1Dao.java

```
@Transactional
public interface User1Dao extends CrudRepository<User1, Long> {     
}
```

User2Dao.java

```
@Transactional
public interface User2Dao extends CrudRepository<User2, Long> {     
}
```

UserController.java

```
@Controller
public class UserController implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired private User1Dao user1Dao;
    @Autowired private User2Dao user2Dao;

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        user1Dao.save(new User1("name 1"));
        user2Dao.save(new User2("name 2"));
    }

}
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.weather_alerts.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/weather_alerts
spring.weather_alerts.username=root
spring.weather_alerts.password=

spring.weather.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/weather
spring.weather.username=root
spring.weather.password=

spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: this looks similar to existing post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308035/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-with-multiple-datasources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data by default looks for an `EntityManagerFactory` bean named "entityManagerFactory", see the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.x/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html#entityManagerFactoryRef--). Since you don't have an `EntityManagerFactory` bean by that name, you're seeing the error.

The solution is to define the `entityManagerFactoryRef` name in your config, e.g.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "weatherManagerFactory")
```

You may need to create two separate config classes, each containing one of your `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` beans, and have a class-level `@EnableJpaRepositories` for each.

Side note, Don't forget to exclude the `DataSourceAutoconfiguration` class in your `Application.java` since you're configuring the datasources yourself.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
```