# Spring JPA Multiple Datasources

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager, transactional

I've seen similar questions on here but haven't been able to find an answer that truely works for me.

I have 2 different datasources, each with its own transaction manager and entity manager factory. They are each defined in their own config class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({
"com.sprint.cst.data.v8p",
"com.sprint.v8p.data",
"com.sprint.v8p.data.util",
"com.sprint.v8p.toptower.repositories",
"com.sprint.v8p.toptower.util"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
    "com.sprint.cst.data.v8p.repository",
    "com.sprint.v8p.repository",
    "com.sprint.eib.data" })
public class JpaConfiguration {

@Value("${cst.db.generateDdl:true}")
boolean generateDdl;
String ddlGenerationStrategy = "create-or-extend-tables";
@Value("${cst.db.showSql:true}")
boolean showSql;

private String[] defaultEntityPackagesToScan =
        new String[]{
        "com.sprint.v8p.domain",
        "com.sprint.v8p.toptower.domain",
        "com.sprint.cst.data.v8p.entity",
        "com.sprint.eib.entity"};

private JpaDialect jpaDialect = new EclipseLinkJpaDialect();


/// Primary JPA
@Primary
@Autowired
@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean defaultEntityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    //em.setPersistenceUnitName(UnitNames.DefaultPersistenceUnit);
    em.setDataSource(dataSource);
    em.setPackagesToScan(defaultEntityPackagesToScan);
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter());
    em.setJpaDialect(jpaDialect);
    em.setJpaProperties(defaultJpaProperties());
    return em;
}

@Primary
@Bean(name="transactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager defaultTransactionManager(
        EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

    return transactionManager;
}

//'Datasource' Transaction Manager
//leveraged by ice events functionality; batch inserts/updates
@Autowired
@Bean(name="dsTransactionManager")
public DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
    DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
    dataSourceTransactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return dataSourceTransactionManager;
}


/// Other Beans

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

@Bean
public PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor persistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor(){
    return new PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
}
```

And:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = {
        "com.sprint.cst.data.v8p.sp2.repository"},
    entityManagerFactoryRef="sp2EntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef="sp2TransactionManager")
public class JpaSp2Configuration {

@Value("${cst.db.generateDdl:true}")
boolean generateDdl;
//@Value("${cst.db.eclipselink.ddl-generation:'create-or-extend-tables'}")
String ddlGenerationStrategy = "create-or-extend-tables";
@Value("${cst.db.showSql:true}")
boolean showSql;

private String[] sp2EntityPackagesToScan =
        new String[]{
        "com.sprint.cst.data.v8p.sp2.entity"};

private JpaDialect jpaDialect = new EclipseLinkJpaDialect();

static final String sp2DataSourceJNDIName = "jdbc/cst-ds-sp2";

/// Secondary JPA
@Bean(name= "sp2EntityManagerFactory")
@Qualifier("sp2EntityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean sp2EntityManagerFactory(@Qualifier("sp2DataSource") DataSource sp2DataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setBeanName("sp2EntityManagerFactory");
    //em.setPersistenceUnitName(UnitNames.Sp2PersistenceUnit);
    em.setDataSource(sp2DataSource);
    em.setPackagesToScan(sp2EntityPackagesToScan);
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter());
    em.setJpaDialect(jpaDialect );
    em.setJpaProperties(defaultJpaProperties());
    return em;
}

@Autowired
@Bean(name="sp2TransactionManager")
@Qualifier("sp2TransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager sp2TransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("sp2EntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean sp2EntityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(sp2EntityManagerFactory.getNativeEntityManagerFactory());
    //transactionManager.setPersistenceUnitName(UnitNames.Sp2PersistenceUnit);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

The datasources exist in a separate datasource config. The 'primary' functions are working fine, the 'SP2' functions are not. For example:

```
@Transactional("sp2TransactionManager")
@Override
public void saveCallHistory(CallHistoryObject callHistoryObject) {
    .
    .
    .

    SolutionInfoEntity solutionInfoResult = solutionInfoRepository.save(callHistoryObject.getSolutionInfoEntity());
    SolutionInfoEntity save = solutionInfoRepository.findOne(callHistoryObject.getSolutionInfoEntity().getSp2Id());
```

The 'save' object here actually does return a result, but nothing is actually persisted in the DB. Any ideas? I feel like I've tried almost everything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot, Spring Data JPA with multiple DataSources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308035/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-with-multiple-datasources)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your repositories are in different packages (At least 1 per dataSource). And in the configuration where you have

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
"com.sprint.cst.data.v8p.repository",
"com.sprint.v8p.repository",
"com.sprint.eib.data" })
```

each connection should have only those repositories enabled.

For example, if dataSource (DS1) operates on package

```
com.spring.ds1.repository
```

and dataSource (DS2) operates on package

```
com.spring.ds2.repository
```

The JpaRepositories configuration would look like this

In DS1 configuration

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.spring.ds1.repository"})
```

In DS2 configuration

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.spring.ds2.repository"})
```

I had similar problems with Cassandra and with the above configuration, I was able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same condition today itself, and found Methods defined in JPARepository implementation (SimpleJAPRepository.java) provided by spring , will not work in second database connection. I have explain my finding http://umeshrsharma.blogspot.in/2016/03/spring-data-jpa-with-multiple-database.html. I might be wrong or missing in configuration. but Still my basic JPA function are not working but user define function are working. If some one had solve this , please explain a bit.