# how multiple database configuration works in Spring boot?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have configured multiple data sources by following :

```
http://roufid.com/spring-boot-multiple-databases-configuration/
```

Please note that I have used same database vendor i.e., MYSQL

**Data source 1:** I made this as @Primary

**DB:** db1

**Tables:** table1, table2, table3

**Data source 2:**

**DB:** db2

**Tables:** table4

When I was trying to query on table4 (data source2: db2), I got exception like below:

```
SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
Table 'db2.table4' doesn't exist
```

But If I changed @Primary from db1 to db2, its working.

Is anyone aware why its behaving like that ?
Any configuration is missing ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot, Spring Data JPA with multiple DataSources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308035/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-with-multiple-datasources)