# Modifying MySql db while Streaming query is being executed

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to use spring data "[Streaming query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-streaming)" feature, but having problems with executing updates at the same time that I'm streaming.

This is the error I get:

```
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1000
Streaming result set com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.result.ResultsetRowsStreaming@483b7dc4 is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.
```

I have two repositories - one is for reading and one is for writing data.

```
@Repository
public interface ArticleRepository extends JpaRepository<Article, Integer> {
    @QueryHints(value = @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "" + Integer.MIN_VALUE))
    @Query("select a from Article a")
    Stream<Article> streamAll();
}

public interface WordRepository extends JpaRepository<Word, Integer> {}
```

The problem with this is that MYSQL does not allow to use same connection for writing to DB when Streaming ResultSet is open for reading. If I use new connection for writing while the Streaming ResultSet is open, everything works OK:

```
String cs = "jdbc:mysql:...";
        try(Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(cs, "root", "123456");
            Statement st1 = c.createStatement();) {
            int res = st1.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO words (word) VALUES ('asd')");
        }
```

Now quesiton is - how to make `WordRepository` to always use new connection and not reuse the same one that is being used by `ArticleRepository`? I wouldn't like to talk directly to JDBC for this, but use same high-level JPA functionality already there. I'm using spring boot and Hikari.

**UPDATE**

After some testing, I found out that it also works If I manually inject new EntityManager into another repo as this:

```
public class WordRepositoryCstmImpl implements WordRepositoryCstm {
  private final EntityManager entityManager;

  WordRepositoryCstmImpl(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
      this.entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
  }
...
```

The problem here is that I have to implement all the methods that are auto-generated by spring data (e.g. `save` must use `this.entityManager.merge` etc.)

So redefined question - how to inject new Entity manager into `public interface WordRepository`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a custom Interface that extends the JPARepository and make a implementation where you set a new DataSource (in your case, maybe a new connection) for the EntityManager.
Something like this: https://www.javabullets.com/access-entitymanager-spring-data-jpa/

Also, see this question: [Spring Boot, Spring Data JPA with multiple DataSources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308035/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-with-multiple-datasources)

Comment: Yes, I updated question with this new findings - If I implement new repo, I can get new EntityManager and it works, but the problem with this is that I have to create all method manually (even save method must be manually created in java).