# Multiple DataSources using Spring Data JDBC and CrudRepository Interface

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jdbc

i have a not trivial question:

My Case:

- Using *Spring Data JDBC*
- Using Two databases
- Usage of `CrudRepository`

As you can see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-data-source-programmatic) in *Spring Data JDBC* you can `extends CrudRepository` and get with *Spring* all Crud Operations out of the box - without an explicit implementation!

It's an easy 4 step process for:

1. define your Properties
2. define your Entities
3. define an interface which extends CrudRepository and
4. make usage of that interface

But in case of using two databases, there is a 5. Step in which you have to define a `@Configuration` class.

I did that these 5 steps as following:

### 0. Pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

### 1. Define your Properties

**application.properties**

```
## D1
datasource.db1.driverClassName=...
datasource.db1.username=...
datasource.db1.password=...
datasource.db1.jdbcUrl=...
## D2
datasource.db2.driverClassName=...
datasource.db2.username=...
datasource.db2.password=...
datasource.db2.jdbcUrl=...
```

### 2. Define your Entities (one for each DB)

**Student.java** // for db1

```
@Table("STUDENT_TABLE")
public class Student{
    @Id
    @Column("MAT_NR")
    private BigDecimal matNr;

    @Column("NAME")
    private String name;
}
```

**Teacher.java** // for db2

```
@Table("TEACHER_TABLE")
public class Teacher{
    @Id
    @Column("EMPLOYEE_NR")
    private BigDecimal employeeNr;

    @Column("NAME")
    private String name;
}
```

### 3. Define your Repositories (one for each DB)

**StudentRepository.java** // for DB1

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, BigDecimal> {}
```

**TeacherRepository.java** // for DB2

```
@Repository
public interface TeacherRepository extends CrudRepository<Teacher, BigDecimal> {}
```

### 4. Define your @Configuration class (one for each DB)

- you can also take both in one class but I did in in that way:

**Db1Config.java**

```
@Configuration
public class Db1Config {
    @Primary
    @Bean("db1DataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("datasource.db1")
    public DataSource db1DataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

**Db2Config.java**

```
@Configuration
public class Db2Config {
    @Bean("db2DataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("datasource.db2")
    public DataSource db2DataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

### 5. Make usage of your interface repositories

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired @Qualifier("studentRepository") StudentRepository studentRepository
    @Autowired @Qualifier("teacherRepository") TeacherRepository teacherRepository 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        studentRepository.findById(30688).ifPresent(System.out::println); // DB1
        teacherRepository.findById(5).ifPresent(System.out::println); // DB2
    }
}
```

These is working fine!

### The problem here is, that `TeacherRepository` not queries DB2, it queries DB1.

which results in an Error: `[...]: Unknown table name:TEACHER`.

### Does anyone knows how i can configure that TeacherRepository use DB2 as DataSource ?

**# Please note before you Answer:**

Here i'm using *Spring Data JDBC* and not *Spring Data JPA*. I know that it works in *Spring Data JPA* like described here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases. I know also that i can make usage of these `JdbcTemplate`. But in that way, i have to write these CRUD Operations by myself which is described [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-JdbcTemplate-tutorial) and that’s not what need.

An answer would be nice of course.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The spring data docs explain how to use multiple data sources. Have you tried following them?

Comment: yes of course. you can see that in the example above. But as you can imagine if I use `StudentRepsository` or `TecherRepository` methods (like `save()`, or `delete()`, ... ) spring queries a database, but the wrong one, because I didn't tell spring which repository for which database is for. that's a configure issue. I don't know how to configure that. In Spring JPA is it so easy as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308035/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-with-multiple-datasources)

Comment: As per Crig the solution above indeed did not work for me. The link provided in the post has solution posted in January 2021
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/issues/544#issuecomment-766664757

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem. My solution had to have my repositories put in 2 separate packages, as per Chris Savory answer, and then define 2 @Configuration classes defining 1 JdbcOperation each.
Here's my full configuration (I have an SQL Server and an H2 data sources):

application.properties

*Please note that these properties are Hikari CP specific. Mileage may vary if you chose a different CP (i.e. Tomcat)*

```
## SQL SERVER DATA SOURCE
spring.sql-server-ds.jdbcUrl= jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1554;databaseName=TestDB
spring.sql-server-ds.username= uteappl
spring.sql-server-ds.password= mypassword

## H2 DATA SOURCE
spring.h2-ds.jdbcUrl= jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;mode=MySQL
spring.h2-ds.username= sa
spring.h2-ds.password= password
```

First H2 @Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableJdbcRepositories(jdbcOperationsRef = "h2JdbcOperations", basePackages = "com.twinkie.repository.h2")
public class H2JdbcConfiguration extends AbstractJdbcConfiguration {


  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.h2-ds")
  public DataSource h2DataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }


  @Bean
  NamedParameterJdbcOperations h2JdbcOperations(@Qualifier("h2DataSource") DataSource sqlServerDs) {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(sqlServerDs);
  }

  @Bean
  public DataSourceInitializer h2DataSourceInitializer(
      @Qualifier("h2DataSource") final DataSource dataSource) {
    ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator(
        new ClassPathResource("schema.sql"));
    DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(resourceDatabasePopulator);
    return dataSourceInitializer;
  }
}
```

Second SQL Server @Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableJdbcRepositories("com.twinkie.repository.sqlserver")
public class SqlServerJdbcConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @Primary
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.sql-server-ds")
  public DataSource sqlServerDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Bean
  @Primary
  NamedParameterJdbcOperations jdbcOperations(
      @Qualifier("sqlServerDataSource") DataSource sqlServerDs) {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(sqlServerDs);
  }

}
```

Then I have my repositories (please note the different packages).

**SQL Server**

```
package com.twinkie.repository.sqlserver;

import com.twinkie.model.SoggettoAnag;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface SoggettoAnagRepository extends CrudRepository<SoggettoAnag, Long> {

  @Query("SELECT * FROM LLA_SOGGETTO_ANAG WHERE sys_timestamp > :sysTimestamp ORDER BY sys_timestamp ASC")
  List<SoggettoAnag> findBySysTimestampGreaterThan(Long sysTimestamp);
}
```

H2

```
package com.twinkie.repository.h2;

import com.twinkie.model.GlSync;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;

public interface GlSyncRepository extends Repository<GlSync, String> {

  @Modifying
  @Query("INSERT INTO GL_SYNC (table_name, last_rowversion) VALUES (:tableName, :rowVersion) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_rowversion = :rowVersion")
  boolean save(String tableName, Long rowVersion);

  @Query("SELECT table_name, last_rowversion FROM gl_sync WHERE table_name = :tableName")
  Optional<GlSync> findById(String tableName);
}
```

Comment: then you have two different applications running or is it one application starting and connect to both dbs ?

Comment: It's one application connecting to 2 different DBs. Both ds are using Hikari connection pools, which I think it's something I need to add to my previous answer since "jdbcUrl" is a property specific to Hikari.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are almost done with configuration but one part is missing in my opinion. You create **Db1Config** and **Db2Config**  and you distinguished between them. But how does spring know what to use and where. My guess is: you have to provide two TransactionManagers(I used for the same problem) and connect repositories (appropriate). In case **TransactionManager** is not in **@EnableJDVCRepositories** please provide more about your code (pom.xml?) I am almost sure you have to create at least two beans more.

I would start [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/bb3b6dbd7d213e7898fb1f2a88bcea8aae8b6c7f/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.java#L58) with a research. That is how spring does it for one datasource and one transaction manager.

Comment: @Rimdal thank you for your answers. Since microsoft put the email notification for your answers as spam in my spam folder I saw your answer to late. sorry. I put the pom.xml in my post above.

Answer (score 0):

Put your Entity and Repository classes/interfaces into different packages.  Then you will need to tell Spring Jpa where to scan for those pakcages in your separate config files

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.yourpackage.repositories1" },
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
@Configuration
public class Db1Config {
```

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.yourpackage.repositories2" },
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
@Configuration
public class Db2Config {
```

Comment: Chris Savory your answer is the right one for `Spring Data JPA` but in case of `Spring Data JDBC` its the wrong one. In `Spring Data JDBC` isn't the annotation `@EnableJpaRepositories`, only `@EnableJDBCRepositories` is aviable as you can see in [Official Spring Ref for [@EnableJdbcRepositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.0.0.M2/api/org/springframework/data/jdbc/repository/config/EnableJdbcRepositories.html)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Rimidal, I don't believe this works.
The docs here indicate that you need a NamedParameterJdbcOperations Bean and (optionally) a TransactionManager Bean.:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#jdbc.java-config

The NamedParameterJdbcOperations is the JDBCTemplate that CrudRepositories will use to hit the database.

There doeesn't seem to be a way to associate the different NamedParameterJdbcOperations/JDBCTemplates with different Repositories.
In my testing this doesn't work anyway. Whichever NamedParameterJdbcOperations Bean is marked @Primary is the one all CrudRepository operations are fed though, regardless of segregating things into different packages and explicitely telling the @Configuration classes which packages to use with @EnableJdbcRepositories.

Comment: In fact, as of late 2020, this appears to be unsupported according to this : https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-321