# How to use JpaRepository for two different datasources?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two data source configuration files that successfully allow my spring app to connect to a snowflake database and another mysql database. I want to have two JpaRepositories for the two databases but both JpaRepositories are pointing to the mysql database. What is the way to use JPA for two different databases?  I can't really find any good info online

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308035/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-with-multiple-datasources

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate each configuration file like this :

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "snowFlakeEntityManager",
    transactionManagerRef = "snowFlakeTransactionManager")
```

here you have specified a name to one `JpaRepo` for snowflake `db` and you can do the same with `mysql`.
Then in Repository class you can annotate the entity manager with the name you have specified before in configuration file like that :

```
@PersistenceContext
@Qualifier("snowFlakeEntityManager")
EntityManager snowFlakeEntityManager;
```